# Coding in Swift 3.0 and I have a page view controller set up with three different views. I want to load the middle view controller in viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

`$` I want to load the middle view controller first on launch so the user can swipe right or left right from the beginning.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    dataSource = self
    self.delegate = self
    configurePageControl()
```

`$` This is where I set the first view controller to start but I want the middle one to load first.

```
    if let firstViewController = orderedViewControllers.first {

        setViewControllers([firstViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

//==============================================================
// MARK: - Properties
//==============================================================
var pageControl = UIPageControl()

//==============================================================
// MARK: - The array of viewControllers
//==============================================================
private(set) lazy var orderedViewControllers: [UIViewController] = {
    return [self.newViewController(view: "Main"), self.newViewController(view: "UserSetting"), self.newViewController(view: "Detail")]
}()

private func newViewController(view: String) -> UIViewController {
    return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "\(view)ViewController")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the 2nd page to be the default - the first one you land on, then just change:

```
if let firstViewController = orderedViewControllers.first {
    setViewControllers([firstViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

to

```
if orderedViewControllers.count > 1 {
    setViewControllers([orderedViewControllers[1]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much @creeperspeak for your fast response.

Comment: @Morty No problem.  Mark this question solved so people know not to add more answers.